# Why does "protection from changes" imply a direction of dependency?

Tags: oop, architecture, solid-principles, dependency-inversion

A little background on me: I'm a self-taught programmer, who started on Python and learned Java when I joined a MegaCorp(TM) 6 years ago. With a Maths degree, I'm pretty solid (no pun intended) on algorithms and critical thinking, but I often find myself with a gap in knowledge related to data structures, design, or other CompSci fundamentals that my peers learned in their Computer Science courses.

To that end, I asked a Senior Engineer on my team for a book recommendation to help fill out my gaps, and he suggested [Clean Architecture](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Clean-Architecture-Craftsmans-Software-Structure/dp/0134494164).

I'm about a third of the way through, and really confused by one of the main motivating factors of the suggestions. Uncle Bob presents many of the ideas and principles (including the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles, which I have heard of before, though I'm still getting to grips with the Liskov Substitution Principle) as being intended to "protect" some portion of a system from requirement to change. There are several examples of this, but the clearest is on page 73:

> If component A should be protected from changes in component B, then
>   component B should depend on component A.

(I should note that, in the absence of any actual definition that I can see, I'm thinking of a "component" as being equivalent to a Java package, though I think that the same thought processes could be applied if a "component" is a separate service - both should present stable usable interfaces to users, whether called locally or over the network)

This claim doesn't have any evidence presented, and it's not self-evident to me. Consider the case of a class `ClassA` in component (package) `ComponentA` which calls `DoStuffReturn doStuff(DoStuffInput input, String someOtherArg)` in `ClassB` in component `ComponentB` - and wherein the call is via either a direct dependency, or via a dependency on an interface *in* `ComponentB` (*not* in `ComponentA`, as Clean Architecture advises)

- If the change in B is a functional change, not a signature change (i.e. - for the same `DoStuffInput` and `String` input, a different `DoStuffReturn` is returned), then no change should be necessary in A:

  - `ClassA`'s call to `ClassB.doStuff` remains valid (same arguments and return type)
  - `ClassA`'s unit tests (which should be using mocked `ClassB`s) should still pass
  - Any fuctional/integration tests that test how `ClassA` and `ClassB` collaborate will need to have their expectations updated, but that's not a change to `ComponentA` (unless those test are *in* `ComponentA` - I've generally seen them externalized in a `ComponentAIntegrationTests` package, but I guess they could also be colocated. That doesn't seem to be what the book is suggesting, though - it's seems to be talking about changes to code, not to tests)
- If the change in B is a signature change to a method other than `doStuff`, then A will not require any changes
- If the change in B is a signature change to `doStuff`, then A *will* require a change - but that would be the case if the interface was in A, too.

(Note that, under the setup Clean Architecture is advocating, wherein the interface for a providing class is in the consuming Component (A), only the first case would constitute a change in B - so that's the only one we really need to be concerned with)

What am I missing? If ComponentA depends on ComponentB, under what circumstances would a change in a class in ComponentB require a change in ComponentA?

(Note that I'm *not* advocating against the use of interfaces - they have multiple other benefits, not least allowing simultaneous development on "both sides" of the contract, and allowing the swapping out of various implementations of the interface)

Answer (score 2):

To explain how we protect one component from changes in another by inverting the direction of dependency, let's first define *component* and *dependency*. In the context of Clean Architecture, components are jar files and dependencies are links between classes.

> Components are the units of deployment. They are the smallest entities that can be deployed as part of a system. In Java they are jar files.  --*page 96*

> The first thing to notice is that all dependencies are *source code* dependencies. An arrow pointing from class A to class B means that the source code of class A mentions the name of class B, but class B mentions nothing about class A.  --*page 72*

Then the question becomes, *what changes do we want to protect components (jars) from*? And the answer is: recompilation, redeployment, and transitive dependencies.

If component `A` depends on component `B`, then any change in `B` (even if that change does not affect an API that `A` consumes) requires `A` to recompile. Furthermore, if the change in `B` adds, removes, or modifies a dependency of `B`, then `A` must reconcile a new transitive dependency, and so the change propagates.

> This dependence means that a change to the source code of [`B`] will force [`A`] to be recompiled and redeployed, even though nothing that it cared about has actually changed.  --*page 84*

> Transitive dependencies are a violation of the general principle that software entities should not depend on things they don't directly use.  --*page 75*

I'm conflating elements from more than one of the SOLID principles here; but they have underlying commonality when it comes to handling change.

Comment: "If component A depends on component B, then any change in B (even if that change does not affect an API that A consumes) requires A to recompile."

That was the bit that I was missing - thank you! I do see that line in the book on page 84, but I assumed that was a "process requirement" ("we have to do this to stay up to date"), rather than an actual fact of Java implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my background, I do have a Computer Science degree, and more than 20 years of professional experience.

The first things first. Nothing is really well defined out there in the field (ok, some math related stuff is). Even basic things like Object-Orientation itself, or Encapsulation, Single Responsibility, and more complex things like Domain-Driven Design, REST, etc. There are wildly differing opinions out there on everything. Sometimes the popular interpretations or these things are the worst option to go with.

What I am trying to say is, keep your skepticism, even in the face of overwhelming authority. Question things and always try to find a valid reason for supporting something. Not just "this is more maintainable this way", that is also just a hypothesis, not evidence.

I happen to think Uncle Bob is a less than ideal source of information regarding object-orientation. [Here](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/07/27/a-detailed-analysis-of-the-clean-architecture-from-an-object-oriented-perspective/) is a detailed critique of the "Clean Architecture" (not the book, the idea) I wrote some time ago if you are interested.

Back to your problem. The quote itself basically says that the direction of dependency runs counter to the spread of change ([here](https://javadevguy.wordpress.com/2017/11/02/transcending-the-limitations-of-the-human-mind/) an article of mine again with some pretty pictures). It doesn't imply (nor should it) that change *always* flows back through the dependency, but it the "knowledge" does. Always. Sometimes changes do not need a physical appearance, like a signature change. Changes in capacity, performance are sometimes breaking changes but not directly visible in the signature. The *meaning* of a method might change without any visible signs too.

So, you are right, internal changes might not cause any other change at all. But the only way to avoid *potential* change from something is to not have a dependency on that something in the first place.

The second best approach is to have a good abstraction and encapsulation, which the "Clean Architecture" does not do well at all unfortunately. The usage of Anemic Objects and pure data as interfaces that Uncle Bob promotes destroys any abstraction or encapsulation a component might have.